# Check if mouse position is in a area pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I try to find in a matrix of `rect` objects, the `rect` that collide with mouse position but doesn't work.

```py
def search_immagine(tab,event_pos):
   for i in range(tab[0]):
       for j in range(tab[0]): #matrix square
           surface=tab[i][j]
           surface=surface.get_rect()
           if surface.collidepoint(event_pos):
                   return True

while not finished:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
           cfinished=True
       if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
           search_image(image,event.pos)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, but it returns a rectangle that always starts at (0, 0) since a *Surface* object has no position.
The Surface is placed at a position when it is `blit` to the display.

You've to set the location of the rectangle, either by a keyword argument, e.g:

```py
def search_immagine(tab,event_pos):
    for i in range(tab):
        for j in range(tab[0]): #matrix square

            x = ... # x coordinate of tab[i][j] = (i * widht)
            y = ... # y coordinate of tab[i][j] = (j * height)

            surface_rect = surface.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))
            if surface_rect.collidepoint(event_pos):
                return True
```

Comment: How can obtain the coordinates of tab[i][j] that is a surface object

Comment: @Pjay Ha, Ha. Are you kidding? How should I know that? I can't see your code. How do you draw the grid?